# PySpark - Split/Filter DataFrame by column's values

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame similar to this example:

```
Timestamp | Word | Count

30/12/2015 | example_1 | 3

29/12/2015 | example_2 | 1

28/12/2015 | example_2 | 9

27/12/2015 | example_3 | 7

... | ... | ...
```

and i want to split this data frame by 'word' column's values to obtain a "list" of DataFrame (to plot some figures in a next step). For example:

**DF1**

```
Timestamp | Word | Count

30/12/2015 | example_1 | 3
```

**DF2**

```
Timestamp | Word | Count

29/12/2015 | example_2 | 1

28/12/2015 | example_2 | 9
```

**DF3**

```
Timestamp | Word | Count

27/12/2015 | example_3 | 7
```

Is there a way to do this with PySpark (1.6)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It won't be efficient but you can map with filter over the list of unique values:

```
words = df.select("Word").distinct().flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
dfs = [df.where(df["Word"] == word) for word in words]
```

Post Spark 2.0

```
words = df.select("Word").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

Comment: Note that after Spark 2.0 the correct command would be
words = df.select("Word").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what zero323 said, I would might add

```
word.persist()
```

before the creation of the dfs, so the "words" dataframe won't need to be transformed each time when you will have an action on each of your "dfs"